# Ubuntu/PHP - WebSocket server doesn't accept more than one connection

Tags: php, ubuntu, websocket

I am trying to develop my first socket server with PHP. The one that I have now works perfectly on my local PC on Win10x64/OpenServer/PHP7.2. But when I tried to move it to the Ubuntu server thing went wrong. My PHP socket server on Ubuntu doesn't accept more that one connection (the first client connected to the server works ok, all the rest get an error during connection to websocket). This is how I initialize it:

```
$clients=array();
$users=array();
$handling=false;
$address=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$port=55533;
$socket=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
if($socket===false){
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
    die();
}
socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1);
socket_bind($socket,$address,$port);
socket_listen($socket);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

while(true)if(!$handling){
    $handling=true;
    usleep(1);
    //some code goes here
    $handling=false;
}
```

And this is how user connects to socket with JS:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+':55533/sockets/webrtc.php')
```

Does someone have some clue why it can happen?

Any help appriciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How your user connect to your websocket ? They run the same code you post here ?

Comment: Just updated the post..

Comment: webrtc.php is your PHP code you paste ?

Comment: webrtc.php is the socket server script. The first part of code is from it. It is a part of my first webrtc app

Comment: So you can't use the script which create the socket to connect to the socket. The socket creation does to be done one time. So start your socket with daemon on your system.

Comment: then why I can connect to it multiple times on my local pc under win 10x64?